# RPM Euro Games keyboard backlight not working in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, command-line, drivers

I have tried using xset led 3 but the light is not glowing. How to fix this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - does it work with another PC? I am thinking the problem could be with your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you are still facing the issue try running the below command in you terminal, it worked for me.

`sudo xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock`